# Some problem with Nginx configuration (reverse proxy to OpenShift's ingress gateway)

Tags: nginx, openshift, nginx-config

I have a problem that I can't solve. The task is to config an external nginx (bare-metal) to make balancing to the OpenShift's ingress gateway host with Istio.
I make a simple nginx config:

```
upstream RobotBalance {
    server ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com:443;
    }

log_format basic '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request"   $status   $bytes_sent '
                 '"$upstream_addr" '
                 '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # listen 80;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/ssl/cert.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    server_name ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com;

    location / {
        # return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; #

        proxy_pass https://RobotBalance;
    
        access_log logs/robot_balance.log basic;
        error_log logs/robot_balance_error.log debug;

        proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        add_header X-Upstream $upstream_addr always;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to send an empry request to the app running at ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com through my nginx. But get a message from openshift's istio about application reachless on given path.

```
curl --cacert /opt/nginx/ssl/root_ca_united.pem --cert /opt/nginx/ssl/published.pem --key /opt/nginx/ssl/private.key --request POST https://my-ngnix-hostname-here/engine-dream/validate -i --verbose -d '{}'
```

- 

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.55.11.22...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-ngnix-hostname-here (10.55.11.22) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/nginx/ssl/root_ca_united.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=EU; O=MY ORG; OU=99CA; CN=my-ngnix-hostname-here
*  start date: Jun  9 07:34:08 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun  9 07:34:08 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my-ngnix-hostname-here" matched cert's "my-ngnix-hostname-here"
*  issuer: DC=ru; DC=org; DC=gamma; CN=My-Org
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x56254b3bf690)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> POST /engine-dream/validate HTTP/2
> Host: my-ngnix-hostname-here
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 2
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< HTTP/2 503 
HTTP/2 503 
< server: nginx
server: nginx
< date: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 09:01:33 GMT
date: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 09:01:33 GMT
< content-type: text/html
content-type: text/html
< pragma: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
< cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< x-upstream: 10.55.111.245:443
x-upstream: 10.55.111.245:443

< 
<html>
...
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Application is not available</h1>
      <p>The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.</p>

      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p class="info">
          Possible reasons you are seeing this page:
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <strong>The host doesn't exist.</strong>
            Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.
          </li>
          <li>
            <strong>The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path.</strong>
            Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
          </li>
          <li>
            <strong>Route and path matches, but all pods are down.</strong>
            Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
...
</html>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection #0 to host my-ngnix-hostname-here left intact
```

But when I'm sending the request directly to ingress, got the correct answer from app.

```
curl --cacert /opt/nginx/ssl/root_ca_united.pem --cert /opt/nginx/ssl/published.pem --key /opt/nginx/ssl/private.key --request POST https://ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com/engine-dream/validate -i --verbose -d '{}'
```

- 

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.55.111.245...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com (10.55.111.245) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/nginx/ssl/root_ca_united.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=EU; O=MY ORG; OU=99CA; CN=ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com
*  start date: Jun  7 10:32:57 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun  7 10:32:57 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com" matched cert's "ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com"
*  issuer: DC=ru; DC=org; DC=gamma; CN=My-Org
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5594f7b31690)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> POST /dsl-engine-dream/validate HTTP/2
> Host: ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 2
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 2147483647)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< HTTP/2 400 
HTTP/2 400 
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 100
content-length: 100
< access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
< server: istio-envoy
server: istio-envoy
< date: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 09:02:40 GMT
date: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 09:02:40 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 4
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 4

< 
{
  "error": " Hello from robot. Robot.app got the empty request!"
* Connection #0 to host ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com left intact
```

Please help. What is wrong with my nginx config? Or maybe there are some features with balancing on ingress with Istio?

Answer (score 0):

This is *likely* because the Ingress Gateway is doing SNI routing, i.e., routing based on the `HOST` header. So when you `curl` "https://ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com/engine-dream/validate", the Ingress Gateway is able to find an application based on the "ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com" `HOST` header.

Whereas, when you'd `curl`ing "https://my-ngnix-hostname-here/engine-dream/validate", you're just passing through the "my-ngnix-hostname-here" `HOST` header, and the Ingress Gateway says, "I don't have an application that matches that hostname ¯\_(ツ)_/¯" and it gives up.

I *bet* that if you tried this `curl`, that the Ingress Gateway would work

```bash
$ curl -H "Host: ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com" --cacert /opt/nginx/ssl/root_ca_united.pem --cert /opt/nginx/ssl/published.pem --key /opt/nginx/ssl/private.key --request POST https://my-ngnix-hostname-here/engine-dream/validate -i --verbose -d '{}'
```

(Notice the `-H "Host: ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com"` header that I'm passing)

In my opinion, what you *should* be doing (well, actually, I don't think that you should be reverse proxying another reverse proxy, the Ingress Gateway, but whatever...if that's your requirement, it is what it is), come up with a new domain name, "apps2.gen1.com" or something. Set up Nginx with `server_name *.apps2.gen1.com". Then when you expose your applications in OpenShift, you can *pick* the hostname that they get exposed as. So expose your application as "ingress-robot.apps2.gen1.com", and you would still point your Upstream` server` to "ingress-robot.apps.gen1.com".

This way, when you're accessing the Nginx box with apps2, it's sending the same apps2 `HOST` header to OpenShift, and OpenShift is able to find the application based on the apps2 route/ingress.

The above feels like a more "correct" solution, however if you want to "hack" it, you could just hardcode the `HOST` header in your Nginx config to match the `HOST` header that the Ingress Gateway is expecting. This feels a bit more rigid and difficult to stay dynamic with, but depending on your requirements, it might "good enough".